# Couldn't convert Object to Base64

Tags: node.js, json

I am unable to convert one object to base64. It throws an error

> The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer,
> ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of
> Client in js

```
   Client {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    qr: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    ready: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    disconnected: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    message_ack: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    message: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)]
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "convert Object to Base64"? Base64 is an encoding for each character in a string, you cannot directly convert an object, it is not made of characters. You can try to convert it to JSON first to get a string representation of the object then encode in base64 if it suits your case, but properties such as functions will be lost.

Comment: An instance of `Client` is not a string, buffer, array, or array-like object. It would also help to be specific about what you expect the output to be; as mentioned, functions won't be included.

Comment: I convert the object as a string by util.inspect(obj). Now, I am unable to convert string to json.

Answer (score 0):

> "The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object.

You can stringify it before trying to set to b64.
`const stringifiedObject = JSON.stringify(<your client object>)`

Then pass convert it to b64

Comment: You should precise that JSON is not a lossless conversion, see the OP's object is mostly made of functions that will not be converted, so I doubt it is going to help that much, also all circular references will make the conversion throw an error. IMO the OP should re-think the strategy

Comment: I also couldn't stringify the object. It throws an error "converting circular structure to json in javascript".